# assembly code junk error, where I'm I going wrong?

Tags: inline-assembly

I'm getting error junk push edipush ecx mov esi after expression...
what is wrong with this? using intel syntax in gcc with -masm=intel turned on..

```
  (
   "    push eax"
    "   push edi"
    "  push ecx"

    " mov al,  byte ptr[esp + 0x8 + 0xC]"
    "mov edi, dword ptr[esp + 0x4 + 0xC]"
    "    mov ecx, dword ptr[esp + 0xC + 0xC]"
    "   rep stosb"

    "  pop ecx"
    " pop edi"
    "pop eax"
    "ret 0xC"
 );
```

Comment: Well, the error is probably due to not ending each 'line' with \n (ie `push eax\n`).  But I'm trying to imagine where you are putting this code that you think it will do what you want.

Comment: thanks David Wohlferd..that was the problem..